# What is the integral of $\exp(z)/(1-z)$ around a circle of radius $1$ centered at $z=1$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am trying to prepare for my first course in complex variables.  I have tried to read my text and as many articles "on line" as I can find but I am very confused.
I wrote $\exp(z)/(1-z)$ as a series in powers of $(z-1)$.  I got:
$$
-e/(z-1) - e(z-1)/2 - e(z-1)^2/6 - \cdots \, .
$$
I thought that the value of the integral would then be $-2\pi i e$.  I used Mathematica with this code:

```
Clear[z]; 
Integrate[Exp[z]/(1 - z), {z, -I, 2 - I, 2 + I, I, -I}] // FullSimplify
```

Mathematica returns $0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: Do you mean the function $\frac{e^z}{1 - z}$ or $\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$?  Because the edit by Anton Grudkin has changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: It should read:  exp(z)/(1-z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $C$ is the unit circle centered at $z=1$,
$$ \oint_C \frac{e^z}{1-z}\,dz = -\oint \frac{e^{1+z}}{z}\,dz = -2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{z+1}}{z},z=0\right) = \color{red}{-2\pi e i}.$$

Comment: The Mathematica code is integrating the function over a rectangle with vertices - I, 2-I, 2+I,and I.  Shouldn't this be the same as integrating over a circle centered at 1?

Comment: If we integrate over ANY closed contour that encircles the point z = 1 the value of the integral will always be the same. right?  I don't know why the Mathematica code returns 0.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: right, $z=1$ is the only pole of such a function. Probably Mathematica returns zero because it takes the principal value of the integral over the full rectangle, not only its counter-clockwise oriented boundary.